# Segmentation fault while function call

Tags: c, c99

I got a struct Chat

```
struct Chat
{
    int m_FD;
    int m_BindPort;
    char m_NameLength;
    char* m_Name;
    char m_PeerCount;
    char** m_PeerList;

} typedef Chat_t;
```

i'm initializing it with this function:

```
int chat_init(Chat_t* this, unsigned int nameLen, char* name, unsigned short int bindPort, unsigned int peerCount, char** peerList)
{
    this->m_NameLength = nameLen;
    this->m_Name = malloc(sizeof(char) * (nameLen+1));
    strcpy(this->m_Name, name);
    this->m_BindPort = bindPort;
    this->m_PeerCount = peerCount;
    this->m_PeerList = malloc(sizeof(char*) * peerCount);
    for(int i=0; i<peerCount; i++)
    {
        this->m_PeerList[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 16); // enough for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\0
        strcpy(this->m_PeerList[i], peerList[i]);
    }

    //Socket initialization for TCP connection...
    //Commenting this out doesn't change anything so i'm hiding it for simplification

    return 0;

}
```

After that i'm calling a second function

```
int chat_communicate(Chat_t* this)
{
    printf("2\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    //Some stuff that doesn't matter because it isn't even called

    return retVar;
}
```

in main like this

```
void main(void)
{
    char* peerList[1];
    char username[USERNAME_MAX_LEN];
    int initRet;
    int loopRet;
    Chat_t chat;

    peerList[0] = "192.168.2.2";

    memset(username, 0, USERNAME_MAX_LEN);

    printf("Please enter your user name: ");
    scanf("%s", username);

    username[USERNAME_MAX_LEN-1] = 0;

    initRet = chat_init(&chat, strlen(username), username, 1234, 1, peerList);

    printf("File Descriptor: %d\n", chat.m_FD);
    printf("Binding Port: %d\n", chat.m_BindPort);
    printf("Name Length: %d\n", chat.m_NameLength);
    printf("Name: %s\n", chat.m_Name);
    printf("Peer Count: %d\n", chat.m_PeerCount);
    for(int i=0; i< chat.m_PeerCount; i++)
    {
      printf("Peer[%d]: %s\n", i, chat.m_PeerList[i]);
    }

    printf("1");
    ret = chat_communicate(&chat);

    //Even more Stuff that isn't even called

}
```

My program outputs the following

```
File Descriptor: 3
Binding Port: 1234
Name Length: 4
Name: User
Peer Count: 1
Peer[0]: 192.168.2.2
1
Segmentation Fault
```

It compiles without errors or even warnings.

You can also assume that every string is null-Terminated The stuff i replaced with comments itn't that complicated but just too much to show.

Every value inside the struct is printed with `printf` right before but when passing this very struct per reference the application crashes.

What i want to know is why i'm getting this Segmentation Fault. Since it appeared while calling a function i thought it is some kind of layout problem but i havn't find anything like that.

**Addition**:
Because some people weren't able to believe me that the code i hid behind "some stuff" comments doesn't change anything i want to state this here **once again**. This code just contains a tcp socket communication and only performs read-operations. I also am able to reproduce the error mentioned above without this code so please don't get stuck with it. Parts does not influence the object under observation at all.

Comment: Where does it crash? Your debugger will tell you.

Comment: What's `peerlist`?  When you can't debug a problem because you don't know what's going wrong, don't leave out code and replace it with `//Stuff`.

Comment: How did you declare and how did you initialize `peerlist`?

Comment: @Michael Walz The code that initializes peerList is shown in `chat_init`. It isn't changed after that. The struct Chat variable is initialized in main on stack and passed to `chat_init` and `chat_communicate` by reference.

Comment: Allocate nameLen + 1, and use strcpy so it null-terminates, other than that the problem is probably in the "stuff that doesn't matter"

Comment: @mnistic It is. I edited my question to show it.

Comment: `username[USERNAME_MAX_LEN-1] = 0;` is probably useless. Show the stuff that sdoesn't matter, it probably _does_ matter.

Comment: We really need a [MCVE] here.

Comment: Many, many subttle problems. One is`this->m_PeerList = malloc(sizeof(char)*peerCount);`

Comment: @Detonar Your last edit shows that `username[USERNAME_MAX_LEN-1] = 0;` isn't harmful here, it's just useless. You really need to provide a __[MCVE]__. This means some  work for you, and you even might find out the cause of the problem yourself in the process.

Comment: @Michael Walz This example might not be 100% minimal because i let the original struct untouched but it's complete and verifiable. the stuff i cut out are just some read operations and lots of working on copys.

Comment: _"The stuff i replaced with comments itn't that complicated but just too much to show."_ And since you're posting here, you don't know what the problem is, so you don't know whether it's relevant or not, so you shouldn't replace it with comments... Also, OT but important: `main()` returns `int`.

Comment: @underscore_d I'm getting the same issues when compiling without the stuff i replaced with comments. This means it's not relevant for this question.

Answer (score 3):

Among other potential problems,

```
this->m_PeerList = malloc(sizeof(char)*peerCount);
```

is clearly wrong.

`m_PeerList` is a `char **`, yet you're only allocating `peerCount` bytes, which only works if a `char *` pointer is one byte on your system - not likely.

Replace it with something like

```
this->m_PeerList = malloc(peerCount * sizeof( *( this->m_peerList ) ) );
```

Note that `sizeof( char )` is always one - by definition.

Answer (score 2):

You're not allocating enough memory for the `this->m_Name`. It should be on more than this if you want it to store the null-terminated string of the name.

That, or we need more information about the `peerList`.

Comment: The username does not cause any problems. i don't even use all reserved chars. How peer list is initialized is shown in `chat_init`. It isn't changed after that.

Comment: @Detonar *The username does not cause any problems.* And how would you know that?  Are you *ever* treating `m_Name` as a NUL-terminated C string with something like `printf()` or using it as a source for anything like a `strcpy()` call?  If you are, the fact that you don't NUL-terminate the data to even make it a string is a huge problem.

Comment: @Andrew Henle username is always NULL-terminated. I'll edit my question to make it more obvious.

Comment: @Detonar *username is always NULL-terminated.*  No, it's **not**.  `strlen()` returns the number of non-`NUL` characters in a string.  You're only `malloc()`'ing exactly that many characters, and copying all the **non**-`NUL` characters to the new memory, without ever adding a `NUL` terminator.

Comment: @Detonar be aware that `username[USERNAME_MAX_LEN-1] = 0;` does not NUL terminate the string, it just puts a NUL into the last element of the `username` array.

Comment: @Michael Walz I know but `scanf` does null-terminate it's string `username[USERNAME_MAX_LEN-1] = 0` is there in case the user inputs something > `USERNAME_MAX_LEN`.

Comment: @Detonar *in case the user inputs something > `USERNAME_MAX_LEN`*  Given the code you've posted, `username[USERNAME_MAX_LEN-1] = 0` is too late - you've already corrupted memory.

Comment: @Detonar In that case, the user has overflowed `username` anyway in that unlimited `scanf` call anyway, and you're walking off the undefined-behavior cliff.

Comment: Oh, and `malloc(sizeof(char)*peerCount)` -> `malloc(sizeof(char*) * peerCount)` (note the '*' after `char`)

Comment: @Michael Walz That `*` is intentional because i'm building an array of pointers.

Comment: @Detonar that's not the point. You need to write `malloc(sizeof(char*) * peerCount)` instead of `malloc(sizeof(char) * peerCount)`. You need to allocated space for `peerCount` _pointers_, not for `peerCount` _chars_.

Comment: @Detonar yes, I've noticed it in the meantime. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Now that you have posted an almost complete code, I was able to spot two problems next to each other:

```
    int chat_init(Chat_t* this, unsigned int nameLen, char* name, unsigned short int bindPort, unsigned int peerCount, char** peerList)
    {
      this->m_NameLength = nameLen;

      this->m_Name = malloc(sizeof(char) * (nameLen + 1)); // correct
  //< this->m_Name = malloc(sizeof(char) * nameLen);       // wrong

      strcpy(this->m_Name, name);                          // correct
  //< memcpy(this->m_Name, name, nameLen);                 // wrong
      ...
```

The lines starting with `//<` is your original code:

Here you don't allocate enough space, you need to account for the NUL terminator:

```
this->m_Name = malloc(sizeof(char) * nameLen);
```

And here you don't copy the NUL terminator:

```
memcpy(this->m_Name, name, nameLen);
```

You really need to be aware how strings work in C.

Comment: Thanks, that really was a problem. Unfortunately not the one causing the Segmentation fault at function call. You geet a vote up anyway.

Comment: @Detonar then there must be more problems elsewhere in the code you don't show. The code in the question with my corrections is correct IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you debug it yourself. If using GCC, compile your code with options `-g -O0`. Then run it with `gdb`:

```
gdb ./a.out
...
(gdb) r
```

If it crashes do:

```
(gdb) bt
```

This will give exactly where it crashes.

Update: There may be potential problems with your code as found by other users. However, memory allocation related issues will not crash your application just on calling function `chat_communicate`. There could be different reasons for this behaviour ranging from stack overflow to improper compilation. Without seeing the whole code it is very difficult to tell. Best advice is to consider review comments by other users and debug it yourself.